# Reset username and password for JFrog

Tags: artifactory

I installed JFrog standalone version on Ubuntu. I dont know my JFrog username and password. I also checked /usr/lib/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/conf/server.xml file but it is does not have any username and password. I also clicked on set me up, but the commandline interface to push an artifact is also prompting for username and password.

[image]

```
ravi@ravi-Inspiron-5537:~$ systemctl status artifactory.service
● artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet E
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor pres
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-08-11 10:11:41 EDT; 37min ago
  Process: 16482 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start
 Main PID: 16532 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/artifactory.service
           ‣ 16532 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jfrog/arti

Aug 11 10:11:17 ravi-Inspiron-5537 su[16508]: Successful su for artifactory by r
Aug 11 10:11:17 ravi-Inspiron-5537 su[16508]: + ??? root:artifactory
Aug 11 10:11:17 ravi-Inspiron-5537 su[16508]: pam_unix(su:session): session open
Aug 11 10:11:18 ravi-Inspiron-5537 artifactoryManage.sh[16482]: Max number of op
Aug 11 10:11:18 ravi-Inspiron-5537 artifactoryManage.sh[16482]: Using ARTIFACTOR
Aug 11 10:11:18 ravi-Inspiron-5537 artifactoryManage.sh[16482]: Using ARTIFACTOR
Aug 11 10:11:18 ravi-Inspiron-5537 artifactoryManage.sh[16482]: Creating directo
Aug 11 10:11:18 ravi-Inspiron-5537 artifactoryManage.sh[16482]: Tomcat started.
Aug 11 10:11:41 ravi-Inspiron-5537 artifactoryManage.sh[16482]: Artifactory Tomc
Aug 11 10:11:41 ravi-Inspiron-5537 systemd[1]: Started Setup Systemd script for 
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default username and password of Artifactory are:

User: admin

Pass: password